# Using c++ openfiledialog in an openGL application

Tags: c++, windows, file, opengl

I've been trying for a while now, and nowhere online gives a working solution for my problem. I've looked at tutorials, and on mdsn, and this website but found nothing. 
I have a bitmap loader:

```
void GLImage::LoadTexture(const char* filename) //load 24bit bitmap images
{
unsigned int texture;
unsigned char info[54]; //the header
FILE * file;

file = fopen(filename, "rb"); //open the file
fread(info, sizeof(unsigned char), 54, file); //read the header for the bmp file

//get image width and height from header
int width = *(int*)&info[18];
int height = *(int*)&info[22];

int size = 3 * width * height; //3 bytes for the colour 
unsigned char* data = new unsigned char[size]; //where the image information is located

fread(data, sizeof(unsigned char), size, file); //read the image and save to data
fclose(file);//close the file

for (int i = 0; i < size; i += 3) //save pixel data to data
{
    unsigned char tmp = data[i];
    data[i] = data[i + 2];
    data[i + 2] = tmp;
}

glGenTextures(1, &texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
this->tex = texture;
delete[] data;
    }
```

Which works fine. 
Now I'm trying to get it to work, but using the OpenFileDialog in c++, not the forms application version (which is really simple).

I have a class then can open the file, and will get the correct filepath. However, saves the filetype as a tchar and not a char. Which means my bitmap loader wont allow it. 
Is there any way of either

A) getting the OpenFileDialog to get the filepath as a char.

or

B) converting the tchar to a char.

Comment: Your texture loader is broken. It cannot open texture files with filenames that contain characters outside the current codepage. You need to use Unicode. If you want to stick to `const char*`, you can pass a UTF-8 encoded character string, and convert it to UTF-16 before calling [_wfopen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb.aspx). Of course, you'll also have to convert from UTF-16 to UTF-8 after [GetOpenFileNameW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646927.aspx) returns.

Comment: Where did you get the BMP file reader code from? Seriously, this code you're using there is popping up again and again, but its wrong, insecure and should not be used. Whoever wrote it first needs to be disciplined. BMP is a tricky beast of file format, that allows many things and some things, like inverse scanline conversion will actually crash the code you're using up there. Here's a collection of BMP files with all their variety: http://entropymine.com/jason/bmpsuite/bmpsuite/html/bmpsuite.html – The only file that's likely to be read without crashing is `g/rgb24.bmp`

Comment: Friends don't let friends write their own BMP file parsers.

Comment: Expanding on datenwolf's comment, there is a BMP decoder built into Windows. It's called [Windows Imaging Component (WIC)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719902.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You could call `GetOpenFilenameA` - the ending A means it will return `CHAR` strings regardless of what a `TCHAR` is. Or you can use `WideCharToMultibyte` to convert from `WCHAR` to `CHAR`.

Another option is to use `_tfopen` in place of `fopen` in your loader, as that accepts `TCHAR*` filenames.

Comment: I now have :
LPOPENFILENAMEA ofn;

 ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));

 ofn->lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
 ofn->hwndOwner = this->Owner;
 ofn->lpstrDefExt = this->DefaultExtension;
 ofn->lpstrFile = this->FileName;
 ofn->lpstrFile[0] = '\0';
 ofn->nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;
 ofn->lpstrFilter = this->Filter;
 ofn->nFilterIndex = this->FilterIndex;
 ofn->lpstrInitialDir = this->InitialDir;
 ofn->lpstrTitle = this->Title;
 ofn->Flags = this->Flags;

 GetOpenFileNameA(ofn);

 return true;

But its not working, ofn doesn't get initialised now?

Comment: Should be `OPENFILENAME ofn;` Then change the `->` to `.` and call `GetOpenFileNameA(&ofn)`